# Find the derivative of $\frac{{(x^3)^{4/3}}}{(2-x)^{4/3}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I tried to solve it using the chain rule first and then doing the quotient rule after. However, I end up with $\frac{24x^2-8x^3(x^3)^{4/3}}{3(2-x)^{7/3}}$ My professor said it's wrong. Kindly explain please.

Comment: Just use the quotient rule first

Answer (score 1):

You must use the quotient rule first. First notice that $(x^3)^{4/3} = x^4$, which can make our lives easier. If $f(x) = \dfrac{x^4}{(2-x)^{4/3}}$, then we have: $$f'(x) = \frac{(x^4)'(2-x)^{4/3} - (x^4)\left((2-x)^{4/3}\right)'}{\left((2-x)^{4/3}\right)^2}$$
where $'$ denotes differentiation with respect to $x$. Now you just use the chain rule to do the $\left((2-x)^{4/3}\right)'$ part. Can you take it from here?

Comment: No.. :( I don't get it where I need to perform the chain rule..

Comment: It it a composition of functions. It is $$(\text{something that depends on } x)^{4/3}$$

The derivative of that $\text{something}$ must come into play somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll need to use the quotient rule:

$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\left(x^{3}\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}}{\left(2-x\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}}\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\left(x^{4}\right)}{\left(2-x\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}}\right)=\frac{\left(2-x\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^4\right)-\left(x^4\right)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left(\left(2-x\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}\right)}{\left(2-x\right)^{\frac{8}{3}}}$$
$$ = \frac{\left(2-x\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}\cdot\left(4x^3\right)-\left(x^4\right)\cdot\left(\frac{4}{3}\cdot\left(2-x\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\cdot\left(-1\right)\right)}{\left(2-x\right)^{\frac{8}{3}}}=\boxed{\frac{4x^3\left(2-x\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}+\frac{4x^4}{3}\cdot\left(2-x\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{\left(2-x\right)^{\frac{8}{3}}}}$$

Double check me to make sure I didn't make any careless arithmetic mistakes...

Answer (score 0):

This may be a different approach but you could consider your formula as:

$f(x) =\frac{(x^3)^{\frac{4}{3}}} {(2-x)^{\frac{4}{3}}} = (x^3)^{\frac{4}{3}} (2-x)^{-\frac{4}{3}} = x^4 (2-x)^{-\frac{4}{3}}$

I prefer using the product rule when differentiating personally; it doesn't involve remembering the quotient rule formula!